# Как задать массив в параметры POST-запроса в RazorPages?

Tags: c#, razor

Есть приложение, которое загружает список вопросов, на которые нужно дать ответы.
Этот массив ответов мне надо отправить на какой-нибудь контроллер.

Razor Pages:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Foo">
        @foreach (var question in test.Questions)
        {
            <div class="list-group-item ">
                @question.QuestionValue
            </div>

            <input type="text" class="input-group-text col-12 justify-content-center mb-2" />
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

Допустим у меня есть DTO-класс, экземпляр которого принимается в параметры метода Foo в контроллере Home.

```
public class InputModel
{
    public ICollection<string> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

В модели, которую привяжем к страницу объявляем `Dictionary<int, string>`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Так как сами вопросы не используются в форме, то передаём их через `ViewBag`:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string SampleAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Вот эту форму добавляем на нашу страницу:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <table>
        @foreach (Question question in ViewBag.Questions)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @question.Body
                </th>
                <td>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <input name= "Answers[@question.Id]" value="@question.SampleAnswer" class="form-control" />
                    </fieldset>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```